# Plot of a especific country using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, geo

I'm totally newbie with geo plots and I'm work in an interactive dashboard. Recently I discover ploty in R. I can reproduce this tutorial https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/ and works perfect for me.

Now I try to reproduce this example (a country split by provinces or states) with other country different of US but scope have only this options: ("world" | "usa" | "europe" | "asia" | "africa" | "north america" | "south america"), don't have any other country than US. And the option of location mode are ( "ISO-3" | "USA-states" | "country names").

My question is: **How can reproduce the example of the Choroplethic Map for other country?**

Comment: For a region other than those that you listed, you have to supply the shapefile yourself. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742879/interactive-choropleth-in-r-of-sweden

Comment: This is way to general as a question. You need to be more specific. With ploytly, mapbox and ggmap can be used to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help, the question that @camile posted is the solution that I need.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build a package that already includes the access to the shapefiles. Quite a bit of work depending on your experience level.

Here is a list of open datasets:
https://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/

If you wanted to recreate a state-level data map, then you would need to find administrative boundaries for your specific country. 
http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

[Administrative regions map of a country with ggmap and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723822/administrative-regions-map-of-a-country-with-ggmap-and-ggplot2)